# Matlab Extrapolation Sign Flip

Tags: matlab, interpolation, extrapolation

I need to extrapolate values

```
values = [4.7725677013567795e-25,5.259671597595681e-25,5.271571307092517e-25,5.804522928756955e-25,5.817596178596506e-25,6.400225475961127e-25,6.414575757297374e-25,7.05099062804588e-25,7.066729446412066e-25];
```

when i run

```
x = [1:9];
valuesextra = interp1(x,values,[10:3120],'spline','extrap');
```

First of all, the extrapolated values get smaller, whereas they should get larger, and secondly the sign of the received values flips after the first value and i get

```
4.34358964678642e-25    -3.23663133644058e-25   -1.77921360688784e-24   -4.14411271161367e-24 ...
```

I have done similar extrapolations with similar data sets where I received a correct extrapolation. What is wrong here? Btw: the data set actually is 450 long not 9, i just posted this minimal example which produces such a flip of the sign.

Answer (score 2):

Your data look like "steps" [image]

that's why could better  use **fit** function instead of **interp1**

The code could look as follows:

```
values = [4.7725677013567795e-25,5.259671597595681e-25,5.271571307092517e-25,5.804522928756955e-25,5.817596178596506e-25,6.400225475961127e-25,6.414575757297374e-25,7.05099062804588e-25,7.066729446412066e-25]';
x = (1:9)';
figure();
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x,values,'.b',x,values,'-g')
hold all;

f = fit(x, values, 'poly1');
plot(f)

xx = (10:3120);
yy = f.p1*xx + f.p2;
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x,values,'.b',x,values,'-g');
hold all;
plot(xx,yy,'.k',xx,yy,'--r')
```

You can choose another fitting function, see help for **fit**, to adjust the **yy** function appropriately

'cubicinterp' - Piecewise cubic interpolation

'smoothingspline' - Smoothing spline (curve)